# Is There A Way To Open SVG from web URL in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, linux

I'm running Inkscape on Linux and usually end up saving SVG's from the web using wget in the terminal.

It would be much easier if I could import/open the SVG directly via URL in Inkscape, but I don't see any clear way to do that.
Please advise?

Comment: This is a question for superuser. For what its worth on windows this works because the os silently handles urls by downloading the file then opening it.

Comment: If your are using KDE, then the feature exist:https://askubuntu.com/a/228706/545149

Comment: Doesn't work for me, either. I hit Ctrl+L to be able to paste the path, and then it tries to load that from my home directory.